# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to www.googleapis.com:443

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-books

Hello I am trying to execute what seems like a very simple snippet of code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:3319613790";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page2 = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($page2);
if($page2 === FALSE) {
  echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

And I get this error when trying to execute it:

> bool(false) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   www.googleapis.com:443

I just want the code to simply run successfully with no errors. I can copy and paste the variable in $url and it displays all the information for the book fine so I don't understand why it won't access the url.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: the api url should be https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:3319613790

Comment: Whoops sorry. My mistake I accidentally deleted the "?" when posting but yes same problem still

Comment: add this line of code
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);

Comment: I still get the same error unfortunately

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.26

Comment: Any change you could upgrade to an newer version?

Comment: Unfortunately it is on a school server so I don't have that kind of access but does it clearly seem it may have something to do with the server itself? It has nothing to do with google api or me needing any kind of api key? I had been told that I might need to register for an API key

Comment: I'm didn't use api key, I read that the possible cause is cURL version with no TTL suport for google's SSL certificate, only by updating to a newer version of PHP would fixit.

Comment: Chances are you need a newer version of PHP, CURL, OpenSSL, and at that point I'd wager a new version of the OS as well. Unless your app needs to run on that particular server, you'd probably be better off setting up a local development environment with a VM and/or Docker.

Comment: I see. Great, thanks so much for your help!